# How to install a .bin file that gives the error that it needs more space in /tmp?

Tags: files, filesystems, tmp

Here is the error:

```
~]$ ./jdev_suite_121200_linux64.bin 
0%....................................................................................................100%
Not enough disk space in dir /tmp/sfx_bG4Mlk, requires at least -1893 MB disk space
** Error during execution, error code = -1.
```

EDIT:

```
~]$ df -h
Filesystem                       Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/dm-3                         50G   25G   22G  54% /
devtmpfs                         1.9G     0  1.9G   0% /dev
tmpfs                            1.9G  1.6M  1.9G   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs                            1.9G  1.1M  1.9G   1% /run
tmpfs                            1.9G     0  1.9G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
tmpfs                            1.9G  904K  1.9G   1% /tmp
/dev/sda2                        477M  130M  319M  29% /boot
/dev/sda1                        200M  9.6M  191M   5% /boot/efi
/dev/mapper/fedora_hostName-home  405G  182G  203G  48% /home
```

Comment: do you have disk memory remaining try `df -h`

Comment: @harish.venkat Yes it's just /tmp

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Most programs use the environment variable `TMPDIR`, and fall back to `/tmp` if there isn't enough room there.

```
TMPDIR=/var/tmp ./jdev_suite_121200_linux64.bin
```

If the program has `/tmp` hardcoded, you can make `/tmp` larger.

```
mount -o remount,size=4g /tmp
```